# How to add theme template in custom page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am very new to PHP and WordPress, I have been facing an issue while creating custom page. I have a custom php page inside plugin folder which is calling in another plugin. Here issue is, Custom page is calling and getting data also, but WordPress theme template and styles are not loading. Getting call to undefined function() error. How to get theme functionality in custom php page?My code is like below.

```
 <?php
   /**
   * The template for displaying all pages
   *
   * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
   * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
   * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
   * different template.
   *
   * @package Sydney
   * @subpackage Sydney
     @since Sydney
   */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
$modelId=$_POST['modelId'];
$reallyPoints=1161;
$modelCost=10;
echo "Model iD : ".$modelId;
echo "Really Points : ".$reallyPoints;
echo "Model cost  : ".$modelCost;
?>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not including the `get_footer()` function before the end of the file? A lot of scripts and styles depend on that function.

Comment: No, There is no any specific reason and Error remains same after adding getfooter() function also.

Comment: if you create a template into the theme and add this code to the template and then from admin for the specific page you could select the template for the page.

Comment: But, my requirement is not that one, I have to add it through in non admin area.